# How to view Recent Order from Magento 2.2.6 through Adminer

Tags: mysql, magento2

How to view Recent Order from Magento 2.2.6 through Adminer as Our admin URL is not working.
Can we run some query to view recent orders and their address ?

Please suggest a query to find out recent orders through Order ID.

I have no database skills to run a complex query.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain the extent of the information you need, but this should get you started. This example query will get you some important information for every order from March 15, 2021 through the present. Adjust the `created_at` date as needed for your purposes.

```
select so.entity_id, soa.firstname, soa.lastname, soa.street,
soa.city, soa.region, soa.postcode, soa.email, soi.sku, soi.name,
soi.qty_ordered, soi.price from sales_order as so join
sales_order_address as soa on so.entity_id=soa.parent_id join
sales_order_item as soi on so.entity_id=soi.order_id where
so.created_at >= '2021-03-15'
```

Comment: This is what I want, perfect. Thank you!